# Performance issues in Linux Multi-heap Multi-thread application

Tags: linux, pthreads

We are porting a multi-process application to multi-threaded architecture. We have the same application running on Windows and it is very performant.

For Linux we are using the pthread libraries. In order to avoid memory contention we have custom heaps, each thread having its own heap. We are using mspace for this custom heap implemention.  However the issue is that this approach is causing a lot of performance overhead. The mspace memory allocations are very slow as compared to the native malloc. This is the bottleneck. We tried the Hoard allocator but that is much worse.

The performance impact is due to:
1. CPU switching: I see more switching in the LWP than in normal multi-processes
2. Memory allocations: I see mspace taking about 7 to 8 times more time than normal malloc

Is there any alternative to acheive multi-heap which is also performant in Linux?

Comment: Have you tried the standard heap, i.e. malloc/new, because it creates a different arenas for different threads if it detects contention? Anyway, you should benchmark your app to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Have you instrumented your application to see what the object size requests look like? That information could help shed some light on what is going on. Big allocations are bad for the Linux allocator and for Hoard, which both resort to mmap once allocations cross some boundary (e.g., 64K or 128K).